# Don't understand proof that if $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy and if some $x_{n_k} \rightarrow x$, then $x_n \rightarrow x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

So by definition of Cauchy, for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $M$ such that for all $i, j \geq M$, then $|x_i - x_j| < \epsilon'/2$ if we let $\epsilon = \epsilon'/2$.

By definition of convergence of a subsequence, for all $\epsilon'' > 0$ and $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n_k \geq N$, then $|x_{n_k} - x| < \epsilon'''/2$ if we let $\epsilon'' = \epsilon'''/2$.

I know the triangle inequality comes into play later, so that for all $\epsilon'''' > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an $L$ such that for all $n \geq L$, $|x_n - x_{n_k}| + |x_{n_k} - x| < \epsilon''''$.

I understand that in the above inequality that we want, we already have that $|x_{n_k} - x| < \epsilon'''/2$, so all we need to do to complete the proof is somehow make $|x_n - x_{n_k}| < \epsilon'/2$. I've read a lot of proofs of this, but they don't explain why they are doing what they are doing and make huge logical jumps as obvious statements. I also don't know why $\epsilon'/2 + \epsilon'''/2 = \epsilon''''$.

Comment: Take a single $\epsilon$. If $x_{n_k}$ is convergent then for $k$ large enough $|x_{n_k}-x|<\epsilon/2$. $x_n$ is Cauchy, so you can find $N$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon/2$ for all $n,m\ge N$. Then the triangle inequality yields the result.

Comment: Your definition of Cauchy sequence is incorrectly stated. " for all i,j ∈ℕ, there exists an M such that for all i,j≥M " makes no sense.

Comment: @d.k.o. The triangle inequality yields $|x_n - x| \leq |x_n - x_{n_k}| + |x_{n_k} - x|$ and we know that if $x_{n_k}$ is convergent then for $k$ large enough $|x_{n_k} - x| < \epsilon/2$, but we have $|x_n - x_{n_k}|$ in the triangle inequality, not $|x_n - x_m|$ so how do I fix this?

Comment: The statement intuitively reads: "Suppose the values of the sequence get arbitrarily close to each other and some of the values get arbitrarily close to a constant; then all of the values get arbitrarily close to a constant"

Comment: @user130018 Just use $n_k$ instead of $m$...